# ¿Como hacer un bucle infinito en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, bucles

He empezado a programar hace muy poco, ayer me propuse a hacer un código simple donde el usuario elige una pregunta y la computadora le responde según lo que elija. Mi problema es que en cierta parte del código,prescisamente, donde se pregunta "¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?", si el usuario elige que si, el código se repita de manera infinita hasta que se le diga otra respuesta, pero solo lo hace 2 veces.

Cualquier ayuda sirve, perdón si el código es feo, cualquier consejo o ayuda es bienvenida

````
print("Programa de cosas que quiero hacer. ¿Quisieras proseguir?")


UserElige = ""

print("1) Sí, lo deseo.")
print("2) No, termina esto.")

opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))


if opción == 1:
    print(random.choice(["Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.", "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.", "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.", "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
    print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
    
    print("1) Sí.")
    print("2) No.")
    
    opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))
    
    if opción == 1:
        print(random.choice(["Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.", "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.", "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.", "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
        print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
        
        for i in [1]:
            if opción == 1:
                    print(random.choice(["Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.", "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.", "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.", "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
                    print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
                    print("1) Sí.")
                    print("2) No.")
                
                    opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))
                    if opción == 1: "Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.", "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.", "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.", "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
                        print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
                        print("1) Sí.")
                        print("2) No.")

    elif opción == 2:
        print("Adiós, entonces.")

elif opción == 2:
    print("En ese caso, adiós.")
    
else:
    print("Vladimir, eso no es una opción.")
    
    for i in [1]:
        print("Una vez más. Tu puedes, Vlad. Programa de cosas que quiero hacer. ¿Quisieras proseguir?")
        
        print("1) Sí, lo deseo.")
        print("2) No, termina esto.")
        opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))```
````

Comment: una pregunta se considera solucionada o resulta cuando has aceptado alguna respuesta, por favor considera aceptar la respuesta que tienes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando quieras hacer un ciclo infinito, usa un `while True:`

```
while True:
    ... hacer alguna cosa ...
```

Un ciclo infinito no para nunca; agreguemos una condición para escapar del ciclo mediante un `break`:

```
while True:
    if condicion_termino:
        # Este es el final, salir
        break;

    ... hacer alguna cosa ...
```

En tu problema, lo que hay que hacer es: preguntar si desea una actividad y luego se elige una al azar:

```
print("1) Sí, lo deseo.")
print("2) No, termina esto.")
opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))
if opción == 1:
    print(random.choice(
        ["Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.",
         "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.",
         "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.",
         "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
    print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
```

Combinando todo tenemos:

```
import random

print("Programa de cosas que quiero hacer. ¿Quisieras proseguir?")

while True:
    print("1) Sí, lo deseo.")
    print("2) No, termina esto.")
    opción = int(input('Selecciona tu respuesta:'))
    if opción == 1:
        print(random.choice(
            ["Comerte una pizza", "Correr por el campo", "Hacer algo productivo.", "Intentar hablar con alguién.",
             "Socializar en Discord.", "Escuchar musica. (sin saltarte.)", "Hablar con tu hermano.",
             "Preguntar por tu abuela", "Hablar con tus padres.", "Intentar escribir una historia.",
             "Mejorar tu fightrole.", "Dormir temprano.", "Ahorarrar para una pc decente."]))
        print("¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?")
    else:
        print("Adios")
        break
```

produce:

```
Programa de cosas que quiero hacer. ¿Quisieras proseguir?
1) Sí, lo deseo.
2) No, termina esto.
Selecciona tu respuesta:1
Hacer algo productivo.
¿No te gusto? Puedes intentar otra vez. ¿Quieres otra actividad?
1) Sí, lo deseo.
2) No, termina esto.
Selecciona tu respuesta:2
Adios

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lo mismo aplicaría tambien usando la sintáxis `while 1:`

Comment: @Carmoreno. Cualquier valor numérico distinto de cero es `True`. Se puede usar `while 2:` también (o 3, 4, ...n). En Python se usa escribir `while True:`.